# Concurrent processing of project reactor's flux

Tags: java, project-reactor

I’m very new to project reactor or reactive programming at large so I'm probably doing something wrong. I’m struggling to build a flow that does the following:

Given a class Entity:

```
Entity {
    private Map<String, String> items;
    public Map<String, String> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}
```

1. read Entity from DB (`ListenableFuture<Entity> readEntity()`)
2. perform some parallel async processing on every item (`boolean processItem(Map.Entry<String, String> item)`)
3. when all finished call doneProcessing (`void doneProcessing(boolean b)`)

Currently my code is:

```
handler = this;
Mono
    .fromFuture(readEntity())
    .doOnError(t -> {
        notifyError(“some err-msg” , t);
        return;
    })
    .doOnSuccess(e -> log.info("Got the Entity: " + e))
    .flatMap( e -> Flux.fromIterable(e.getItems().entrySet()))
    .all(handler::processItem)
    .consume(handler::doneProcessing);
```

The thing works, but the `handler::processItem` calls don’t run concurrently on all items. I tried using `dispatchOn` and `publishOn` with both `io` and `async` `SchedulerGroup` and with various parameters, but still the calls run serially on one thread.
What am I doing wrong?

Apart, I’m sure that in general the above can be improved so any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You need another flatMap that forks and joins computation for each individual map element:

```
Mono.fromFuture(readEntity())
.flatMap(v -> Flux.fromIterable(v.getItems().entrySet()))
.flatMap(v -> Flux.just(v)
                .publishOn(SchedulerGroup.io())
                .doOnNext(handler::processItem))
.consume(handler::doneProcessing);
```

Comment: Thanks @akarnokd for your suggestion which sounds promising, though due to time pressure I moved to CompletableFutures which seem simpler and have reasonable documantation.